# Spring Integration debounce/deduplicate

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

Is there some component in Spring Integration that could be used to filter out duplicates in a specified time frame?

I am looking for something like [Debounce from ReactiveX](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/debounce.html)

In my project I am sending a Payload containing a UUID and I want to filter out multiple Payloads with the same UUID if the are sent through the queue within 10 seconds for example - then I want to only let the last on through as long as no other Payload with the same UUID comes within the next 10 seconds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to @Apokralipsa I was able to do this by adding the following aggregator:

```
<int:aggregator
            input-channel="enrichedChannel"
            output-channel="aggregatedChannel"
            group-timeout-expression="size() ge 1 ? 10000 : -1"
            send-partial-result-on-expiry="true"
            expire-groups-upon-timeout="true"
            correlation-strategy-expression="payload.id"
            release-strategy-expression="false" />
```

Comment: Doesn't look like you need such a complex `group-timeout-expression`. The group timeout is really activated when we have at least one message arrived into the aggregator. So, you logic in that ternary operator is just equal to the `group-timeout="10000"`

Answer (score 4):

You can use an [aggregator](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/htmlsingle/#aggregator) for that purpose. What you would need set up is

- the correlation strategy to recognize messages that are duplicated
- the release strategy to consider a single message to be a completed group
- `expire-groups-upon-completion` to `false`, so that the group will not be deleted as soon as it is completed and sent out
- `group-timeout` to, for example, for 10 seconds
- keep `expire-groups-upon-timeout` as `true` (it is so by default)

From the reference documentation:

> ([expire-groups-upon-completion](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/htmlsingle/#CO3-18)) When set to true (default false), completed groups are removed from the message store, allowing subsequent messages with the same correlation to form a new group. The default behavior is to send messages with the same correlation as a completed group to the discard-channel.

Comment: I wanted to advice Idempotent Receiver (http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#idempotent-receiver), but Aggregator with the `group-timeout` is really much better solution. With the proper `releaseStrategy` you can emit only one and only the last message in that time window.

Comment: Thanks for your help, this is going into the right direction. I was able to configure the aggregator so that only one message is sent of multiple incoming. But it looks like the first message is sent as soon as it comes in and the next messages within the timeout are not sent. I would need the opposite: all message should be hold until within the timeout no new duplicate comes in - then the last message should be sent.

Comment: @ArtemBilan, sorry for necroposting on that one: So this solution, in deed, does work but keeps all message objects alive until the group is released, so in high throughput scenarios it causes GC pressure. Is there some good way to discard the duplicates when they are about to be added to the message group?

Comment: You probably can look into a persistent `MessageStore` where we don't keep messages in the memory, but only pull them all on group release. Or you can override an `addMessagesToGroup()` for your `MessageGroupStore` and implement that de-duplication logic you are looking for. This is really not an aggregator responsibility to have that logic internally.